# Where should I put this line "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"?

Tags: autostart, rvm

where should I put this line  `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` it make it work when system start or  how to install rvm on Ubuntu correctly for all users in my system?

Answer (score 2):

Any scripts placed in the directory `/etc/profile.d` are sourced by all users when they start a shell.

I see a package `ruby-rvm` exists, but you would need to check what version it is and what configuration it sets up.

Comment: I install `ruby-rvm` and update rvm. After that I install ruby 1.9.3 in /usr/share/ruby-rvm

Comment: Package ruby-rvm is a old version of rvm, it also contains some bugs and introduces some random errors not know to standard rvm installations, her is a fix I wrote some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

Answer (score 1):

To make that work you need to add that line to `~/.bashrc`.
But note that this will only work for the current user.

Comment: `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` not work

Answer (score 0):

This line should be added to `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.zprofile`, this is automatically done when you run rvm updater with `--auto` flag, as it was not available in older versions best path would be:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm get stable --auto
```

as you are using ubuntu you should also check instructions for [gnome terminal](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/).